# Troubleshooting "Using $this when not in object context" when trying to access property of child class from parent class

Tags: php, static-methods

I have a main class which initializes another class in a function of main class and I need to get a variable (in this case `$this->db`) from the main class to that another class. For example, I have a main class `Wordle_Admin`:

```
class Wordle_Admin
{
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
   }

   public function views()
   {
       include 'Wordle_Admin_Views.php';
       $wsa = new Wordle_Admin_Views();
       $view = @$_GET['view'];
       $id = @$_GET['id'];
       $type = @$_GET['type'];
       $action = @$_GET['action'];
       $msg = @$_GET['msg'];

       if( !empty( $view ) && method_exists( $wsa, $view ) ):
           $wsa::$view($id, $type, $action, $msg);
       elseif( !empty( $view ) && !method_exists( $wsa, $view ) ):
           echo'View does not exist.';
       else:
           $wsa::index($id, $type, $action, $msg);
       endif;
   }    

}
```

And I have another class:

```
class Wordle_Admin_Views extends Wordle_Admin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index( $id = "", $type = "", $action = "", $msg = "" )
    {
        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM wordle_post');
    }
}
```

I can not use `$this->db` in `Wordle_Admin_Views`, it returns:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\Server\wordle\w-includes\Wordle_Admin_Views.php on line 22

So my question is, how can I pass a variable from parent class to class? All kind of help is appreciated, pointers on what to do differently are also accepted with open hands.

Comment: `Using $this when not in object context` has nothing to do with parents or children. It means you're using `$this` in a function that's called statically, or outside an object. How are you calling these functions?

Comment: I use Wordle_Admin::views() in a layout file (as in what user sees) to output pages that operate as functions (Wordle_Admin_Views's functions). My goal is to be able to use mysqli in Wordle_Admin_Views without initializing a new connection and instead using the connection that was initialized in Wordle_Admin. If that is possible, that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that this might be a part of issue:

```
   include 'Wordle_Admin_Views.php';
   $wsa = new Wordle_Admin_Views();

   /* blah blah */

   if( !empty( $view ) && method_exists( $wsa, $view ) ):
       $wsa::$view($id, $type, $action, $msg);
   elseif( !empty( $view ) && !method_exists( $wsa, $view ) ):
       echo'View does not exist.';
   else:
       $wsa::index($id, $type, $action, $msg);
   endif;
```

You are trying to access static function not on a class name but on object. It should be either `Wordle_Admin_Views::$view()` or `$wsa->$view()`.

Have you actually learned php or are you pretending that it is some other language (python ?) and just "winging it".

Comment: Calling a static method or property on an object instance is actually an allowed shortcut. Not that it's necessarily a good idea, of course.

Comment: @deceze , i think he was doing it other way around: calling a normal method as static ( with `$this` used inside that method ).

Comment: It fixed the problem I had , thank you. As for have I learned; no, I have not. However I am learning. Also no, am not pretending as I don't really know any other language. I'm here to learn because for me it seems that learning from other's mistakes is the best way. As for motivation, I actually like a harsh word every now and then. It keeps the spirit alive and reminds me that I'm nowhere near where I want to be. So double thanks for that.

Comment: Which is why I answered in my downvoted way. Nothing in the class declared it as static, so calling it with :: would yield the same results. So I thought.

Comment: @KaiQing , yeah , that was the first thought , but testing it in http://codepad.viper-7.com indicated that undeclared class variables are not set as `private`.

Answer (score 1):

Your concrete problem is that you're calling the method statically. You don't have an object in a static context, so you can't use `$this`.

Your other problem seems to be that you're slightly misunderstanding inheritance. Since the DB connection is only created when you *instantiate* an object (`new Worlde_Admin`), the same goes for the child.

A `Wordle_Admin_Views` does not automatically have access to a DB connection that may or may not have been created in some instance of `Worlde_Admin`. Only that `Worlde_Admin` instance has that DB connection. You need to instantiate a `Wordle_Admin_Views` so it will have a connection as well (because it inherited the methods how to do so from `Worlde_Admin`).

```
$admin  = new Worlde_Admin;  // $admin now has its own db connection
$admin2 = new Worlde_Admin;  // $admin2 now has another db connection
$view   = new Wordle_Admin_Views;  // $view has yet another connection

Wordle_Admin_Views::index();  // this has no db connection
```

You should be looking into Dependency Injection, which means you create one `mysqli` instance outside your classes and inject that into each one when it is instantiated.

```
$db = new mysqli(...);

$admin = new Worlde_Admin($db);
$view  = new Wordle_Admin_Views($db);
```

Comment: First of all, a lovely answer. This solution works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

in your world admin class try this...

```
class Wordle_Admin
{
    protected $db;

}
```

then your db var should be inherited when you call $this->db, assuming $this->db was defined in the parent class.

Comment: I'm guessing this was downvoted because, while it addresses what the OP *says* is the problem, it doesn't solve the *actual* problem (inferred from comments and the nature of the error message).

Comment: Did I misread something? declaring protected $db in the parent class makes $db visible to classes extending that controller. In the child controller you can call $this->db and it will return the parent $db if instantiated. Was that not the question?

Comment: @phoenix - really? he said this "I need to get a variable (in this case $this->db) from the main class to that another class." not WHY it wasn't working. He asked how to get it to work.

Comment: You could be right.  I didn't downvote your answer; just curious if there might be a way to improve it to get it some upvotes.

Comment: Since the constructor sets `$this->db`, which thereby defaults to `public`, it would work with or without this declaration.

Comment: @Kai Qing Judging by the error message, there is no object and consequently no `$this`. That's probably why this answer was downvoted. I'm actually not even sure if that statement is needed in php, I think the variable gets generated automatically by the constructor if it's not defined already. When you instantiate an object obviously...

Comment: The error lied in Wordle_Admin::views where instead of -> I used :: as @tereško answered.

Comment: @jeroen yeah, $this will fail if no object, but declaring $db as protected in the parent class will resolve that in this case since his parent constructor defines $this->db. $this is needed. Even if he is trying to call it statically, php will not care unless he specifically declares the method as static, which he did not.

Comment: @Kai If the property is not specifically declared as `private` in the parent, it absolutely does not matter whether it is declared at all. See http://codepad.org/6zjeEeZz

Comment: @deceze - aah this is a good point and also mentioned by teresko above but in different verbiage. Thanks